# Based on the function's CPE, how is the lower bound calculated?

Tags: c, linux, performance, optimization

I have come across a way of computing the lower bound on the CPE (determined by the critical path) for the data type float. However, I am not sure where the numbers have come from and I need some clarification before I attempt to compute similar bounds.

This is what I have come accross:
**`(4+3)/3 = 2.33`**

I assume it is divided by 3 because of the CPE value, but I am confused as to where the (4+3) comes from.

This function has a CPE of 3.00 for integer and floating-point data.

```
void inner4(vec_ptr u, vec_ptr v, data t *dest) {
    long i; 
    long length = vec_length(u);
    data_t *udata = get_vec_start(u);
    data_t *udata = get_vec_start(v);
    data_t sum = (data_t) 0;
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++){
        sum = sum + udata[i] * vdata[i]'
    }
    *dest = sum;
}
```

[image]

Comment: I do not know what a function's CPE is.  provide a link?

Comment: @ryyker cycles per element https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycles_per_instruction

Comment: @Pauline - thank you for the link.  I read it.  It appears that your `(4+3)/3 = 2.33`, representing the lower bound CPE (or CPI) for float is a simplification if a ratio, probably derived similarly to those in the examples shown in the link you provided.  In particular Example 2, which also is for type  `float`, but with different processor _instruction mix_ and _clock cycle count_ than for the unit you reference in your post.

Comment: @Pauline Are you sure the CPE for both Integer and floating point is 3.00?

Comment: @Pauline Assuming `data_t` to be a floating-point type, you have a total of two floating-point instruction `sum + udata[i] * vdata[i]` and one integer type instruction `i++` in each loop. Rest is control transfer and data transfer. This means you can calculate the CPI for float and integer only for a single loop and it holds for any number of length. 

You then only need to use the following formula:
`CPI = (2*CPI(floating-point) + 1*CPI(integer))/3`

Comment: Cycles per array element isn't the same thing as cycles per instruction, since you can't process one element per instruction except with a fully-unrolled loop.  Or with vectors that hold 4 elements, it's only a coincidence if you use 4 instructions per element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...I assume it is divided by 3 because of the CPE value, but I am
>   confused as to where the (4+3) comes from.

It appears that your `(4+3)/3 = 2.33`, representing the lower bound CPE, (or CPI) for float is a simplification of a ratio (perhaps after factoring), derived as those shown in the examples in the *[link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycles_per_instruction)* you provided in comments.  i.e. summing up the count of instructions per type, each one multiplied by its corresponding clock cycles, all divided by the total instruction count.

Example 2 in the link, also for type  `float`, but with a different processor *instruction mix* and *clock cycle count* than for the unit you reference in your post provides illustration.  Although there is not enough information given in your post to know exactly how those values were derived, the formula given in the link clearly shows how the ratios are constructed.

Following the same form given in Example 2: and given the following (contrived) instruction mix and cycle counts, albeit a very simplified example (i.e. only two instruction types)  this shows how your ratio *could have* been derived:

```
Instruction type    Instruction count   Clock cycle count  

Floating point      6000                2
Control transfer    3000                3
```

The ratio would then be:

```
(6000*2 + 3000*3)/9000  
After factoring:    

(4 + 3)/3 - Ratio is the sum of two instruction types, each multiplied
            by their corresponding cycle count, all divided by the total
            instructions in the specific program, then factored to
            lowest terms.
```